# Cartesian Product from INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

```
SELECT A.x, A.y, B.m, B.n, C.p 
FROM A,B,C 
WHERE A.x = B.l 
  AND A.y = B.m 
  AND B.n = C.q
```

or

```
SELECT A.x, A.y, B.m, B.n, C.p 
FROM A 
 INNER JOIN B ON A.x = B.l AND A.y = B.m 
 INNER JOIN C ON B.n = C.q
```

gives Cartesian product. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your expected output and sample data is much appreciated

Comment: Which SQL server type are you using?

Comment: Neither of those queries will return a cartesian product

Answer (score 0):

just use below sql it will give you Cartesian product

```
SELECT A.x, A.y, B.m, B.n, C.p FROM A,B,C
```